# How to delete an image from application programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

We can add an image to an photo album using

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"];  

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, 
          @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Is it possible to delete the added image later? If so, how can I give a user the option to delete the added image.

Comment: Your question is not clear - can you explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: you need to clear your question, like you using image directly or storing it in document directory. If Directly then no problem for you just set nil in uiimageview object otherwise delete it from document directory and then after set nil to uiimage you. I think this may help you to clear out your questions....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but if you're using documents directory to save this image, use the following method:

### **Documents Directory Approach**

**Save**

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        ALog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}
```

**Load**

```
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]];

    return result;
}
```

**Remove**

```
-(void) removeFile:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directory {
    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError * error = nil;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileName, extension]]]) {
        BOOL itemRemoved = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directory, fileName, extension] error:&error];
        if (itemRemoved == TRUE) {
            ALog(@"Item \"%@\" Removed", fileName);
        } else {
            ALog(@"Item \"%@\" Removal Failed", fileName);
        }
    } else {
        ALog(@"Item \"%@\" does not exist", fileName);
    }
}
```

**How-To**

*Save*

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[self saveImage:yourImage withFileName:@"YourImageName" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:path];
```

*Load*

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage * myImage = [self loadImage:@"YourImageName" ofType@"png" inDirectory:path];
```

*Remove*

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[self removeFile:@"YourImageName" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:path];
```

***Note:***
*The 'png' extension is used as default in this case, but you can change it to whatever image extension you're using.*

### **Photo Albums Approach**

**Suggestion**

Save your files to the documents directory folder using the above methods, read your images within your app. If the user does not like a photo he/she can then delete it from within your app (documents directory). If the user likes the photo, he/she can add it to photo albums or when the application exits you can add code to add the photos to your photo albums.

The documents directory approach is used by many photo applications. The methods above will help you if you use the documents directory approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myfile.example"];
NSString *filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:fileName];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

[fileManager removeItemAtPath:myFilePath error:NULL];
```

You will have to close the file first if it is open.

Sorry, rereading I think I misunerstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a button named as Delete.When he clicks on it you have to load images in a tableview so that you can give the delete option in the tableview (take care of the UserId based on this only you need to load the images)

```
NSFileManager *defaultFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *filePath = @"pass the Path here";
 [defaultFileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant delete a image saved on photo album. User should manually do that. Note that you are not specifying a file name when saving to photo album. `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, 
          @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);`. iOS dynamically assign a file name to the image to be saved.